# eliminar archivo del servidor con laravel

Tags: php, laravel

tengo un inconveniente y creo que estoy realizando algo que no corresponde, necesitaba subir al servidor, cosa que realice sin inconvenientes, mi codigo de subida es el siguiente:

En el filesytems.php tengo lo siguiente

```
'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

En mi Controlador cuando quise movier el archivo al servidor lo realice de la siguiente manera:

```
if ($request->hasFile('archivo')) {
                $file = $request->file('archivo');
                $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $newName = "/personal/".$name;
                $file->move(public_path("personal/"), $name);
            }else{
                echo "Debes subir documento"
            }
```

Pero ahora tengo inconvenientes para eliminarlo del servidor, tengo el siguiente código:

En mi tabla, tengo un campo llamado adjunto que guarda la información de la siguiente manera `/usuarios/100128000.jpg`

```
    $personal = Usuarios::find($id);
    if($contents = Storage::get(public_path($personal->adjunto))){
       Storage::delete(public_path($personal->adjunto));
    }
    $personal->delete();
```

Por ejemplo, quise imprimir lo siguiente `$path` me arroja lo siguiente

```
$path = public_path($personal->adjunto);
C:\Users\JUANJO\Desktop\Trabajos - Proyecto\public\/usuarios/100128000.jpg"
```

Como me arroja `\/` dentro de mi ruta, quite el `/` para continuar, imprimiendo nuevamente mi `$path`

```
$adjunto = substr($personal->adjunto, 1);
   $path = public_path($adjunto);
   dd($path);
```

Imprimiendo lo siguiente:

```
C:\Users\JUANJO\Desktop\Trabajos - Proyecto\public\usuarios/100128000.jpg"
```

Pero claramente estoy realizando algo mal  que no me esta permitiendo borrar la imagen del servidor, ayuda plis

Answer (score 0):

Intenta utilizando esta linea de código.

```
return Storage::disk('public')->delete('URL'.$ARCHIVO_A_ELIMINAR);
```

Comment: En realidad tampoco me funciono.

Comment: te marca algún error?

Comment: Subi mis cambios al servidor y probe otra vez pero me arroja lo siguiente: /var/www/lc/public/usuarios/100128000.jpg. Mi error se provoca en esta parte if($contents = Storage::get(public_path($personal->adjunto))){ Storage::delete(public_path($personal->adjunto)); } ya que arroja FileNotFoundException :'(.  Si dejo tu línea Storage::disk('public')->delete('URL'.$ARCHIVO_A_ELIMINAR); arroja el mismo error

Comment: Pero es un servidor local?

Comment: Subo mis cambios automaticamente a través de SourTree y eso lo compruebo a traves de filezilla (sftp)

Comment: Creo que es porque tratas de buscar un servidor local y el archivo no lo encuentra en la dirección que tratas de buscar. Quiero decir que si estas tratando de buscar esos archivos en tu computadora local desde el proyecto que se encuentra en el servidor no creo que puedas hacerlo de esa manera que estas tratando.

Comment: Ocupas almacenar esos archivos en un servidor y tener esas claves para configurar un nuevo **DISK** en el archivo **filesystems.php**

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices, pero si ejecuto los cambios y prueba mi ruta (no local) tampoco me funciona, aunque si me arroja /var/www/lc/public/usuarios/100128000.jpg.

Comment: si estas en local y te envía ese error revisa el archivo **filesystems.php** porque puede y que la ruta este mal

Comment: Ese error no es local

Comment: entonces si es lo que mencionaba en los anteriores comentario. Es porque el servidor no encuentra la ruta a la que tratas de acceder ya que es un sistemas **no local**

Comment: Alan es que no entiendo porque, tan experto no soy en esto, pero no entiendo porque me dice que el archivo no existe, ya que si lo veo y no responde como necesito, no se si hay algo que me falte enviar :'(

Comment: tu quieres acceder a esta ruta **C:\Users\JUANJO\Desktop\Trabajos**?

Comment: No, quiero acceder a la ruta del servidor, pero lo corregi con el unlink de php y me funciono sin inconvenientes, muchas gracias